# Enforce CSS class to all elements in a table

Tags: html, css

I have a css which works perfectly:

```
.border
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}

.clean
{
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

No problem. But to create a table with border I will have to do:

```
<table class="border">
<tr>
<td class="border"></td>
<td class="border"></td>
</tr>
```

I find this brutally tedious. Isn't there a way to go:

```
<table class="border">
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

with the same result as the above?
I want an "excel-like" square grid, not only a border around the table (second example).

Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to apply the class inside all your tds. Just use like this:

```
table.border,table.border td{//Applying border in table html
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is:

```
.border {  /* matches all element with that class */
  border-collapse: collapse; /* excel like (collapse cells border together) */
  border:1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}
.border td { /* matches all td which have "border" in a parent class element */
  border:1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}
```

`